# Formatting object borders

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

a quick (and probably easy) question.  I am trying to write some code that changes the colour of a border of a control. Below is the operation I would like to perform on the control "Project_Phase" embeded in my form. Strangely, this code does nothing.  Many thanks.

```
Me!Project_Phase.BorderColor = vbYellow
Me!Project_Phase.BorderWidth = 5
```

Comment: Check that `BorderStyle` is not set to `Transparent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that `BorderStyle` is not set to `Transparent`